# Durable Functions - infinite execution with state doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm setting up a durable Function that should run infinitely with by invoking itself every hour and keeping a state. The function compiles, bus fails at run with the following error:

> 2017-07-12T07:04:05.614 Exception while executing function: Functions.DurableTimer. 
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'context'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Cannot convert  to DurableOrchestrationContext.

**Function code**

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"

using System;
using System.Threading;

public static async Task Run(DurableOrchestrationContext context, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Durable function executed at: {context.CurrentUtcDateTime}");

    // sleep for one hour between calls
    DateTime nextExecution = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddHours(1);
    await context.CreateTimer(nextExecution, CancellationToken.None);

    int counterState = context.GetInput<int>();
    log.Info($"Counter state: {counterState}");

    counterState++;

    context.ContinueAsNew(counterState); 
}
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "context",
      "type": "orchestrationTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: It's odd that it would compile but report an error like this. I wonder if it could be some kind of type/assembly issue. Just to be safe, can you confirm you followed the installation steps here? https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/articles/installation.html#deploying-the-durable-task-binding-extension-in-azure

Comment: Yep @ChrisGillum. of D:\home\BindingExtensions has the DurableTask folder with the 37 files in it.

Comment: Ah, I think I know the problem. Let me post it as a possible answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to manually trigger the orchestration function in the portal UI, which unfortunately is not supported at this time. I verified by trying to reproduce your exact scenario and clicking the **Run** button in the portal. I've opened a bug to track this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/10

Assuming that's the case, you can workaround it by creating a separate function which knows how to trigger your orchestrator function.  Here is the example I posted in the GitHub issue:

**Code**

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"

using System;

public static async Task Run(string functionName, DurableOrchestrationClient starter, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Starting orchestration named: {functionName}");
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(functionName, null);
    log.Info($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");   
}
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "manualTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "functionName"
    },
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "type": "orchestrationClient",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

This is a generic function that can start any orchestrator function by name. In your case, you can put `DurableTimer` as the input.

Apologies that this is non-obvious and thanks for your patience as we smooth out the experience. :)

Comment: Thank you @Chris. While this allows me to kick off my durable function, I'm hitting another problem. I'll follow up on GH.